# Octopus Deploy transform of SessionState provider

Tags: xml, web-config, session-state, octopus-deploy, web.config-transform

For our local debugging we use this in our web.config

```
<sessionState mode="Custom" customProvider="MyAppStateStore" timeout="480">
  <providers>
    <add name="MyAppStateStore" type="Microsoft.Web.Redis.RedisSessionStateProvider" 
         applicationName="MyApp" 
         host="127.0.0.1" 
         accessKey="" 
         ssl="false" />
  </providers>
</sessionState>
```

On our Dev server we would like it to be this:

```
<sessionState mode="Custom" customProvider="MyAppStateStore" timeout="480">
  <providers>
    <add name="MyAppStateStore" type="Microsoft.Web.Redis.RedisSessionStateProvider"
         applicationName="MyApp" 
         host="www.oursite.com.backends"
         port="1234"
         databaseId="1"
         accessKey=""
         connectionTimeoutInMilliseconds="5000"
         operationTimeoutInMilliseconds="1000"
         throwOnError="true"
         ssl="false" />
  </providers>
</sessionState>
```

For most of our web.config appSettings we are using OD's Variables for transforms during deployment. Is there a way to include a complex setting like this in the transform without using a transform `.config` file?

Answer (score 0):

Using a config transform (web..config) is the easiest approach. You can combine it with the "substitute variables in files" feature if you want to use placeholders. For example:

**web.production.config**:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration xmlns:xdt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/XML-Document-Transform">
  <sessionState mode="Custom" customProvider="MyAppStateStore" timeout="480">
    <providers>
      <add 
         xdt:Transform="Replace" 
         xdt:Locator="Match(name)"
         name="MyAppStateStore" 
         type="Microsoft.Web.Redis.RedisSessionStateProvider"
         applicationName="MyApp" 
         host="#{Host}"
         port="1234"
         databaseId="1"
         accessKey=""
         connectionTimeoutInMilliseconds="5000"
         operationTimeoutInMilliseconds="1000"
         throwOnError="true"
         ssl="false" />
    </providers>
  </sessionState>
</configuration>
```

You can then define `Host` as a variable in Octopus.

There's lots of information and examples here:

https://octopus.com/docs/deploying-applications/configuration-files